# How to get all the columns values for a specific Column value pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataset.

| state | code |
| --- | --- |
| OH | A |
| OH | B |
| NY | C |
| NY | D |

I want to get the following, and then the details into a csv file. How do I do it? I tried groupBy but it seems to not work.

| state | code |
| --- | --- |
| OH | A,B |
| NY | C,D |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a group by using `collect_set` or `collect_list`

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.groupBy("state").agg(F.collect_set("code"))
```